# Grouping the list

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

Let's assume that I have randomly generated list

```
 llist = {{0, 1}, {2, 1}, {4, 4}, {0, 3}, {3, 4}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 0}};
```

We can represent this data using the following plot,

[image]

I want to group the elements, but I can only group them by same x elements or y elements.

For example, if I group them with the same x elements, I got five groups,

[image]

```
{{{4,4},{3,4}},{{0,3},{2,3}},{{2,2}},{{0,1},{2,1}},{{2,0}}}
```

If I group them with the same y elements, I got four groups

[image]

```
{{{0, 1},{0, 3}},{{2, 1},{2, 2},{2, 3},{2, 0}},{{3, 4}},{{4, 4}}}
```

However, if I group them with x and y simultaneously, I can reduce the group by three.

[image]

I am looking for an efficient way to group them. I attach my naive coding method.

---

```
(*Where I want to save group*)
group1 = {};
(*Count them*)
countx = Table[{i, Count[llist[[All, 1]], i]}, {i, 0, 4}];
county = Table[{i, Count[llist[[All, 2]], i]}, {i, 0, 4}];
(*Find the bigger grouping*)
mcx = Select[countx, #[[2]] == Max[countx[[All, 2]]] &][[1]];
mcy = Select[county, #[[2]] == Max[county[[All, 2]]] &][[1]];
(*if x grouping is more,than group them by x and remove their group \
from the list,if y grouping is more or equal,group them by y and remove from \
the list, and call that list as llist1*)
If[mcx[[2]] > 
   mcy[[2]], {group1 = 
    Append[group1, 
     llist[[Flatten[Position[llist[[All, 1]], mcx[[1]]]]]]], 
   llist1 = 
    Delete[llist, Position[llist[[All, 1]], mcx[[1]]]]}, {group1 = 
    Append[group1, 
     llist[[Flatten[Position[llist[[All, 2]], mcy[[1]]]]]]], 
   llist1 = Delete[llist, Position[llist[[All, 2]], mcy[[1]]]]}];
```

group1 will have the first largest elements, {{{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 0}}}, and the new list llist1 will now have {{0, 1}, {4, 4}, {0, 3}, {3, 4}}.

If I try again,

```
(*Repeat*)
countx1 = Table[{i, Count[llist1[[All, 1]], i]}, {i, 0, 4}];
county1 = Table[{i, Count[llist1[[All, 2]], i]}, {i, 0, 4}];
mcx1 = Select[countx1, #[[2]] == Max[countx1[[All, 2]]] &][[1]];
mcy1 = Select[county1, #[[2]] == Max[county1[[All, 2]]] &][[1]];
If[mcx1[[2]] > 
   mcy1[[2]], {group1 = 
    Append[group1, 
     llist1[[Flatten[Position[llist1[[All, 1]], mcx1[[1]]]]]]], 
   llist2 = 
    Delete[llist1, Position[llist1[[All, 1]], mcx1[[1]]]]}, {group1 = 
    Append[group1, llist1[[Flatten[Position[llist1[[All, 2]], mcy1[[1]]]]]]], 
llist2 = Delete[llist1, Position[llist1[[All, 2]], mcy1[[1]]]]}];
```

I can find my second biggest group, {{4, 4}, {3, 4}}, and my last list will be {{0, 1}, {0, 3}}

```
(*Repeat*)
countx2 = Table[{i, Count[llist2[[All, 1]], i]}, {i, 0, 4}];
county2 = Table[{i, Count[llist2[[All, 2]], i]}, {i, 0, 4}];
mcx2 = Select[countx2, #[[2]] == Max[countx2[[All, 2]]] &][[1]];
mcy2 = Select[county2, #[[2]] == Max[county2[[All, 2]]] &][[1]];
If[mcx2[[2]] > 
   mcy2[[2]], {group1 = 
    Append[group1, 
     llist2[[Flatten[Position[llist2[[All, 1]], mcx2[[1]]]]]]], 
   llist3 = 
    Delete[llist2, Position[llist2[[All, 1]], mcx2[[1]]]]}, {group1 = 
    Append[group1, 
     llist2[[Flatten[Position[llist2[[All, 2]], mcy2[[1]]]]]]], 
   llist3 = Delete[llist2, Position[llist2[[All, 2]], mcy2[[1]]]]}];
```

My last repeat will group the last elements, so you will get

```
group1
(*{{{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 0}}, {{4, 4}, {3, 4}}, {{4, 4}, {3, 4}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 3}}}*)
```

and llist3 will be empty, so we can stop the algorithm.

Comment: I don't understand how you decide the groupings in your last example. If you have an example of code that reproduces the grouping you want, please share it.

Comment: @MarcoB I modified the question with example

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if you could also explain the logic behind the code. What feature are you using for grouping?

Comment: @MarcoB I add the comments too!

Comment: `First@MaximalBy[Length][GatherBy[llist, #] & /@ {First, Last}]`?

Comment: @kglr Thank you for the nice shortcode. That gives a really nice solution for the first case. Can you get the last case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `GatherBy` (or `GroupBy`) to group by the first or second column:

```
GatherBy[llist, First] // Column
```

[image]

```
GatherBy[llist, Last] // Column
```

[image]

To get the last grouping in OP, define two functions `take` and `drop` and use them with `NestWhileList`:

```
ClearAll[take, drop]
take[lst_] := First @ MaximalBy[Length][Join @@ (GatherBy[lst, #] & /@ {First, Last})]; 
drop[lst_] := DeleteCases[Alternatives @@ take @ lst] @ lst

take /@ Most@NestWhileList[drop, llist, # =!= {} &] // Column
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `Reap/Sow` with `take`:

```
ClearAll[take2]
take2 = Reap[NestWhileList[
  DeleteCases[Alternatives @@ Sow[take @ #]] @ # &, #, # =!= {} &]][[2, 1]] &;

take2 @ llist // Column
```

[image]

#### Pictures

```
ClearAll[matrixPlot]

matrixPlot = Module[{groups = #}, 
    MatrixPlot[Reverse @ SparseArray @ Flatten @ 
     MapIndexed[Thread[1 + Reverse /@ # -> #2[[1]]] &, groups], 
     DataRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}, 
     Mesh -> All, 
     ColorRules -> Map[# -> ColorData[97]@# &, Range[Length @ groups]], 
     ImageSize -> 1 -> 70, 
     PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@groups], 
       InputForm /@ groups, 
       LegendFunction -> (Column[{Style["  groups:", 16], #}] &)]]] &;


Column[matrixPlot /@ {GatherBy[llist, First], GatherBy[llist, Last], take2 @ llist}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is alot better solution! Thank you so much!